# Servicestack MultiTenancy

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have ServiceStack v4.0.60 installed and am looking to ChangeDb in AppHost configuration as per the following:

```
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c => 
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(defaultDbConn, SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider));

var dbFactory = container.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>();

//Register NamedConnection
dbFactory.RegisterConnection("Reporting", ReportConnString, PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);

//Register DialectProvider
dbFactory.RegisterDialectProvider("Sqlite", SqliteDialect.Provider);
```

However  Visual Studio is telling me that 'RegisterConnection' and 'RegisterDialectProvider' is not part of IDbConnectionFactory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not part of [IDbConnectionFactory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/Data/IDbConnectionFactory.cs) but it is on `OrmLiteConnectionFactory`, so you'd need to reference the concrete type, e.g:

```
var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(defaultDbConn, SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider);
container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(dbFactory);

//Register NamedConnection
dbFactory.RegisterConnection("Reporting", ReportConnString, PostgreSqlDialect.Provider);

//Register DialectProvider
dbFactory.RegisterDialectProvider("Sqlite", SqliteDialect.Provider);
```